# Can you copy rest bone positions of one armature to another armature as non-rest pose

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

I have 2 models: A and B. Both have armatures. Model A has straight hands, model B has bent hands. I'm trying to make model A fit model B's armature, is there a way I can copy the positions of B's hand bones and paste them to A's hand bones as a pose so the hands will match B's armature? Both armatures have the same amount of bones, and the bones' names are the same. I tried copying the pose but since it's the rest pose for model B it doesn't do anything.

It doesn't matter if A's armature is matching B's armature, it's purely about making A's mesh match B's armature, so if there's another way of going about this then that works too.

If possible I want to avoid copy-pasting every value for every bone 1 by 1.

Comment: Are you saying that B has bent hands in the Rest Position, ie some bones where bent/rotated in Edit Mode, so that you want to copy all the rotations of same bones in A to same in B?  I think you'd have to resort to python, as using a poseLib from A (pose from Clear Transform >> All), will cause the Pose >> Apply to not edit the (Rest/Edited) bone rotations, but only apply the rotations RELATIVE to Rest Pose.  In python, I'm thinking you'd be able to step through each bone and apply the rotations bone to bone.

Comment: Thinking more about python, this would also be difficult.   In edit, you really work with bone head and tail position vectors, rather than rotations.  And you'd want to apply a new positioning and be sure that the character mesh follows the bone repositioning.

Comment: Give each bone you want copied a copy transforms bone constraint, targeting its twin in the other rig.  I would expect that scripts or addons that can do this more automatically (on the basis of name) would exist someplace, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks, using copy transforms works
I wasn't able to find a script and I don't know much python so I have to do without, but atleast it makes things a lot easier